# Class transitions raster

Tags: r, gis

How can I compute the number of class transitions between two different rasters?
For example: how many times the cell with value 5 changed to cells with value 2
5->2 (13 times)
But using a matrix transition

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nc=5, nr=5)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 2
s <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)) * 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily with package raster and function crosstab too.

```
 library(raster)
r <- raster(nc=5, nr=5)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 2
s <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)) * 3)
crosstab(r,s)

      layer.2
layer.1 1 2 3
      0 1 6 1
      1 0 3 1
      2 2 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` on data frame with two columns (where columns are values of two matrixes).

```
set.seed(2222)
# prepare some data
A <- matrix(round(runif(25, 1, 5)), 5)
B <- matrix(round(runif(25, 1, 5)), 5)

# construct data.frame
AB <- data.frame(as.numeric(A), as.numeric(B))

# compute number of pairs:
AB_trans <- table(AB)
>AB_trans
   B
A   1 2 3 4 5
  1 0 0 1 2 0
  2 1 1 1 1 1
  3 1 1 0 1 2
  4 0 2 2 2 0
  5 0 2 1 1 2
```

So, in this example, cells with value 5 from matrix A were changed to cells with values 2 in matrix B 2 times.